# Cannot query using OleDb and DbExtensions

Tags: ado.net, oledb, dbextensions

this question is about using https://github.com/maxtoroq/DbExtensions

```
DbConnection connection = Database.CreateConnection("name=myconx");
var query = SQL.SELECT("u.username").FROM("Users u").WHERE("Id={0}", 1);
IEnumerable<Users> products = connection.Map<Users>(query);
```

The following code is returning null don't know why ?

```
 getDbProviderFactory(connection);
```

and here's the definition no idea about the next code purpose :

```
static readonly Func<DbConnection, DbProviderFactory> getDbProviderFactory =
           (Func<DbConnection, DbProviderFactory>)Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(Func<DbConnection, DbProviderFactory>), typeof(DbConnection).GetProperty("DbProviderFactory", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic).GetGetMethod(nonPublic: true));
```

and here's my connection string

```
<add name="myconx" connectionString="Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Integrated Security=SSPI;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=ES;Initial Catalog=TestDB;Data Source=ITA-PC\SQLR2" providerName="System.Data.OleDb"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that OleDbConnection does not override the [DbProviderFactory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.data.common.dbconnection.dbproviderfactory) property , which is also an issue with OdbcConnection. I will report these as bugs.

If you have the source code you could try something like this:

```
  public static DbProviderFactory GetProviderFactory(this DbConnection connection) {

     if (connection is OleDbConnection)
        return OleDbFactory.Instance;

     return getDbProviderFactory(connection);
  }
```